# glm formula halts ONLY WHEN variables aren't treated categorically

Tags: statsmodels, glm

So I have `statsmodels` and I see that `smf.glm` halts only when the variables aren't categorical (i.e. wrapped with a `C()`). If I modify the formula so that some of the variables are wrapped with a `C()` then they do not halt.

Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "halt"? You need to provide more information about the problem.

Comment: "halt" = The constructor succeeds in constructing the object and fitting it.

Comment: That's still not any helpful information. What does "not halt" mean? Do you get an exception or non-convergence, or your computer goes to sleep? You need to provide a full description of the problem, and preferably also a minimum working example that shows it.